# Anylogic inventory statistics

Tags: anylogic

There is a patient flow where a patient arrives to the hospital. At some point it arrives in a hospital room, where it seizes a doctor. The doctor needs some items from a medical cart. The ressource carts, has an agent Cart with four variables. Each variable is an integer and when I seize a cart I want two of the integers to go down by one(Meaning that the doctor uses two units to heal the patient).
On seize unit I have the following code "((Cart)unit).red--;((Cart)unit).allPatients--;"

The patient flow goes on with the patient leaving the room, and a little later hospital. Before the cart goes back to its original place with the new variables I want to check if any one the items is out of stock.

[Wrapup task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFSS7.jpg) On WrapUp on the release block there is a boolean to check if anyone of the variables have reached 0 with the following code "agent.red==0 || agent.allPatients==0" and agent type is here defined as my ressource Carts. 
It never seems to enter this boolean, which brings me to my question:
How can I make sure it enters the boolean? Is one of the two expressions wrong? Under advanced tab in seize I have to mention the patient as the primary flow which is maybe why it doesnt enter? If it is because its not preemted how can I make sure it is? I have used the wrapup task somewhere else in the simulation to clean up a room after the patient left it without problems, which indicates that there are a problem with the variables and the first expression. 
When I run the simualation I cant follow the progress of the variables. Any small fixes for that?

Comment: the wrap-up action is activated only when the agent is preempted... is this your case?
In the analysis palette you have dataset and statistics elements to collect statistics of variables... use them

Comment: hmm how can I make sure if the agent is preemted? With the previous help you gave the system runs without any warnings, but it never enters the boolean, so something tells me the agent is not preemted.  Yearh I have used the pallette to make statistics of utalization of the ressources. But in this case I want the utalization of the variables inside an agent which doesnt seems to be same straightforward. I cant seem to find any assistance in the "HELP" article or other projects. .

Comment: Long story short: Patient arrives, seized different items( the cart with the four variables for instance), but when I realese the cart I want to make the check if there are still items left in the cart before the next patient arrives.

Comment: For the system not to crash I have to choose the patient in the advanced tab in both the seize and realese block for the system not to crash. It gives me and exception othervise saying patient cannot be cast to cart

Comment: if you don't know if you agent is preempted then it's not... in which case putting code in the wrap-up action is useless... it will never happen... 

In the dataset normally you put the variable to get statistics.. when it comes to agents you have to know what you want to do.. for instance if you want the mean of a variable you would do instead of variable in the dataset, you can do average(agents,a->a.variable); But you have to explain with a lot of detail what you want to do, otherwise nobody will be able to help you... because you are right, it is not straightforward

Comment: How can I make it is preemted? In did not put the code in the wrap up action, but did it as your earlier helped with, see edited picture or other link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236764/anylogic-inventory-management. The lowest point in the realease block is called wrapup too. It never enters, so either variables isnt changed by the code in the seize block or there is something with the boolean expression. I cant see the variables when I run the model, which is the reason I mentioned the statistics.

Comment: The way you ask for help is by creating the smallest model that reproduces your problem.. basically your question in stackoverflow should be such that I can take all the information and create the model myself... but ok, upload the model and give me a link and I will take a look